# Storyboard: Views with navigation controller before tabbar

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have a little problem related to implementing a tabbar with navigationcontrollers, when I have two views before the tabbarcontroller, which also uses a navigationcontroller. 
This is my setup in StoryBoard

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P4Zw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei3xa.png

But this is not working as I want, because I get two navigationbars (Picture number 2) when I enter the tabbar screen. I know I just can delete the navigation controllers in the tabbar or change the segue to modal, but if I do so, I would not have the ability to add individuel UIBarbuttons to each tabbar view or set individuel navigationbar titles. I would also like to use the push segue through out the app, as it is a kind of an "step by step" app. My question is: How I can eliminate the double navigationbar, when I enter the tabbar, but still have the ability to set a title for each view related to the tab and continue to use the push segue and a navigationcontroller? 
I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set buttons both in the Storyboard and programmatically and they can be different at different stages of your view controller. You should thus delete the second and third navigation controllers and either drag and drop the buttons you want where you need them, and/or deal with it programmatically if necessary.

One example of what you could do programmatically:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *yourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourSelector)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonSegueBackToAccueil;
```

This creates a UIBarButtonItem for the controller you are in and places it as the left button of the navigation controller bar. It will run the method "yourSelector" when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You -can- set individual buttons for each view controller. Grab a tab bar item and drag it to the navigation bar of whichever view controller you want. You can also set the individual title of each view controller. Like you said, there is no reason for the 2nd and 3rd navigation controller you added right after the tab bar controller.